# Smoke Detector Turns on Randomly: After removing Popcorn ceiling and repainting

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, drywall, smoke-detectors

I removed the popcorn ceiling and repainted the ceilings at my place. The drywall contractors forgot to cover the smoke detector. Obviously there was popcorn ceiling leftover, dust, slight moisture. Now when I take a shower my smoke/Carbon monoxide detector goes off and starts ringing. Anyone know the reasoning behind this, and how to fix? I'll will probably just get a new one for $20.

Comment: It got wet from popcorn removal. Get a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most smoke detectors use a dual chamber where 1 chamber is sealed and another is open. They use a small radioactive device to create ionization of the chamber when there is smoke. Many of the disposable types really are not designed to be cleaned but using a clean dry compressed air or “duster” spray may clean it out, also pulling a vacuum across the openings can clean them out. If the chamber gets contaminated further by wet or oily air it will be ruined. In industrial facilities we regularly clean them and many times cleaning is successful but not always.